# How can I create a new element in Xamarin based on Label?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using this element very frequently:

```
<Label Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
       Text="Front Side" 
       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
```

Is there a way that I can create a new element called SettingsText and then just have to specify

```
<SettingText Text="Front Side" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the style in  App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>    
        <Style x:Key="CustomStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="StartAndExpand" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ListItemTextStyle" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomStyle}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then, Create a class inherit from Label and use the style written above.Of course you can define the style in SettingText directly. But if in app you can use it everywhere in your application.

```
class SettingText : Label
{
    public SettingText()
    {
        Style = Application.Current.Resources["ListItemTextStyle"] as Style;
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
<local:SettingText Text="123"/>
```

Don't forget add this

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectName"
```

#### Update

`ListItemTextStyle` is a Style which defines the style of label in the XAML, find it and Write those properties in the customize class.

```
class SettingText : Label
{
    public SettingText()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        TextColor = Color.Red;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
    }
}
```

Or

```
class SettingText : Label
{
    public SettingText()
    {
        var LabelStyle = new Style(typeof(Label))
        {
            Setters = {
                new Setter {Property = Label.TextColorProperty, Value = Color.Red},
                new Setter {Property = Label.BackgroundColorProperty,  Value = Color.Red},
                new Setter {Property = Label.VerticalOptionsProperty,  Value = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand},
            }
        };

        this.Style = LabelStyle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also give an example of how I could define the style in SettingsText directly.  I'm thinking it might be best to keep everything in one place. In particular I am not sure of how to define this in C# :  Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}

Comment: @Alan2 ListItemTextStyle is a style which you define in XAML at somewhere in your application , just find out it and write the perporties in the constructor  of SettingText.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the custom label and set the property in this constructor as you want.

You need to create custom label like below:

```
namespace ProjectName
public class SettingText : Label 
    {
        public SettingText()
        {
            this.Style = new Style(typeof(Label)){
                         Setters = {
                                   new Setter {Property = Label.HorizontalOptionsProperty, Value = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand},
                                   new Setter {Property = Label.VerticalOptionsProperty,  Value = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand}
                                    }
                         };
            this.TextColor = Color.Red;
        }

    }
```

Add  namespace for custom label in your Xaml file:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectName"
```

Now you can use this custom label in your xaml like:

```
<local:SettingText Text="Hello" />
```